# 2D lattice random walk plots in functional style

Tags: functional-programming, random, r, higher-order-functions, data-visualization

To practice writing code in the functional programming style, I wrote a program to plot two-dimensional lattice [random walks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk). I'd appreciate any feedback about how to improve its "functionaliness".

```
possibleSteps <- list(c(-1,0), c(0,-1), c(1,0), c(0,1))

step <- function(x) {
        return(unlist(sample(possibleSteps, 1)))
}

takeRandomWalk <- function(nSteps) {
        coordPairs <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(1:nSteps, step), accumulate = T)
        x <- sapply(coordPairs, `[`, 1)
        y <- sapply(coordPairs, `[`, 2)
        return(list(x, y))
}

plotRandomWalk <- function(nSteps, margins) {
        walkObj <- takeRandomWalk(nSteps)
        plot(seq(-margins,margins), seq(-margins,margins),
             type = 'n', xlab = "", ylab = "")
        lines(walkObj[[1]], walkObj[[2]])
}
```

Call `plotRandomWalk(10000, 80)` for an example.

**EDIT**

I have now compiled a far schnazier version as a shiny app:

[Check it out!](https://buckminster.shinyapps.io/randomWalks/)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good.  The code is functional with the exception of using
`return`, which is not necessary as the last value will be returned
anyway, so I'd simplify to the following and also in the interested of
efficiency only compute the `coords` once and without `seq`, as `:` is
shorter:

```
step <- function(x) {
        unlist(sample(possibleSteps, 1))
}

takeRandomWalk <- function(nSteps) {
        coordPairs <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(1:nSteps, step), accumulate = T)
        x <- sapply(coordPairs, `[`, 1)
        y <- sapply(coordPairs, `[`, 2)
        list(x, y)
}

plotRandomWalk <- function(nSteps, margins) {
        walkObj <- takeRandomWalk(nSteps)
        coords <- -margins:margins
        plot(coords, coords, type = 'n', xlab = "", ylab = "")
        lines(walkObj[[1]], walkObj[[2]])
}
```

`Reduce` with `accumulate` is pretty cool, I think this is the first
time I've seen an `accumulate` parameter on a reduce-like function
anywhere.

Now I think you know that, but usually R code like this would be written
with less lists and more data frames or matrixes.  That doesn't mean the
code isn't functional:  As long as it's using functions, not mutating
things and using functional abstractions instead of imperative
constructs it's fine.

So the following is probably more idiomatic and at the same time uses
more efficient representations for the data:

```
possibleSteps <- matrix(c(-1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE,
                        dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y")))
```

Gives a matrix with named columns like so, which will be the representation
throughout the rest of the code (which is good for consistency):

```
> possibleSteps
      X  Y
[1,] -1  0
[2,]  0 -1
[3,]  1  0
[4,]  0  1
```

The random walk will still be created by `sample`, except it's sampling
indexes.  `cbind` will create a new matrix from the two accumulated sums
(`cumsum`):

```
takeRandomWalk <- function(nSteps) {
        indexes <- sample(1:dim(possibleSteps)[1], nSteps, TRUE)
        walk <- possibleSteps[indexes,]
        cbind(X = cumsum(walk[,1]), Y = cumsum(walk[,2]))
}
```

And finally `plotRandomWalk` is a bit simpler as we can just give
`lines` the constructed coordinates matrix:

```
plotRandomWalk <- function(nSteps, margins) {
        coords <- -margins:margins
        plot(coords, coords, type = 'n', xlab = "", ylab = "")
        lines(takeRandomWalk(nSteps))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you seem focused on functional programming, the main suggestion I'll have is regarding the use of arguments. It is recommended functions use all their arguments (see how `step` does not use `x`) and more importantly, that they only use variables that are either passed as arguments or defined inside their body (see how `step` uses `possibleSteps` that is defined outside). Fixing for that and making other personal but minor changes, the final code would look like this:

```
takeRandomStep <- function(possibleSteps) sample(possibleSteps, 1)[[1]]

takeRandomWalk <- function(possibleSteps, nSteps) {
   randomWalk <- replicate(nSteps, takeRandomStep(possibleSteps))

   data.frame(X = cumsum(randomWalk[1, ]),
              Y = cumsum(randomWalk[2, ]))
}

plotRandomWalk <- function(possibleSteps, nSteps, margins = NULL) {
   walkObj <- takeRandomWalk(possibleSteps, nSteps)
   if (is.null(margins)) {
      maxVal  <- max(abs(unlist(walkObj)))
      margins <- ceiling(maxVal) + 1L
   }
   xylim <- c(-margins, margins)

   plot(walkObj, type = "l", xlim = xylim, ylim = xylim)
}

# test code
testSteps <- list(c(-1,0), c(0,-1), c(1,0), c(0,1))
plotRandomWalk(testSteps, 10000)
```

You will notice and hopefully appreciate:

1. the use of `replicate` rather than looping over an unused argument
2. the use of `plot`'s `xlim` and `ylim` arguments rather than the trick you used
3. making `margins` an optional argument

Comment: I had forgotten about `replicate`--thanks, that's super helpful!